# How to escape the spaces and hyphens in append function of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm using jQuery append function to dynamically create dropdowns. But when I do this:

```
var external = "External - Customer view";
```

In `append` function: `'<option value='+internal+'>'`

It is rendering it as

```
<option value="External" -="" customer="" view="">
```

I want it to render as:

```
<option value="External - Customer view">
```

Comment: Append should be :

'<option value=\"'+internal+'\">'

Comment: or `.append($("<option>").val(internal) );` Goodness gracious, that looks ugly. It'd work, though.

Comment: Thank you both of you. It works. I'll accept the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the value that way (which you can), as you're using jQuery anyway, let it do the work for you.

```
let myOption = $("<option>");
myOption.val(internal);

foo.append(myOption);
```